# JSF: invoking a javascript after a successful creation

Tags: jsf

my current code.

```
<h:form>
   <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
       <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
   </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        // some form input stuff here..

    </h:panelGrid>         

   <h:commandButton class="register-btn" action="#{accountController.create}" value="#{bundle.Register}">
        <f:ajax event="action" execute="@form" render="messagePanel"/>
   </h:commandButton>                       
</h:form>
```

messagePanel is where the validation errors displays.

create() method

```
public String create() {
        try {

            getFacadeUser().create(currentUser);

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/index.xhtml");
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

is it possible to invoke a javascript after a successful creation? currently my create form is a pop up modal, what i want is to just hide the modal after a successful creation rather than redirecting to a page.

i'm using JSF 2.1

Comment: To be clear, you want to invoke some JS in the redirected `/index.xhtml` page?

Comment: If you redirected user to `index.xhtml` your dialog doesn't exist on that page. What you will hide?

Comment: nope, currently my code is redirecting the page after creation, i dont want this. instead, on the same page i just want to close the pop up modal containing the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With standard JSF (read: no component libraries or utility libraries such as PrimeFaces or OmniFaces which have ways to make this easier), your best bet is to conditionally render `<script>` element.

```
<h:panelGroup id="script">
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty accountController.currentUser.id}">
        alert('User successfully created!');
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Reference it in `<f:ajax ... render="script">`.

Comment: oh, hmm.. if i implement primefaces? is there simpler and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `RequestContext#execute()`. By the way.. You don't say "I implement PrimeFaces". Cagatay Civici is the only who does that. You should say "I use PrimeFaces" or "I install PrimeFaces".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component binding for your dialog in your managed bean and hide the dialog from your function using that binding. I think the type of object which represents your component binding is framework specific (although all of them probably extend UIComponent), so you need to specify what JSF implementation you are using for a full solution. I implemented this very use case in ADF for example.

This is an example from ADF:
`<af:popup id="sample" binding="#{viewScope.myBean.myPopup}">`

and in the managed bean:

`RichPopup myPopup;

    ...

public void onSave() {

    //save user

    myPopup.hide();

}`

Comment: This looks more like a comment than a direct answer.